# $|G:H|$ and $|H|$ are coprime

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Suppose $G$ is a finite group with a normal subgroup, $K$, and another subgroup, $H$, such that $[G:H]$ and $|H|$ are coprime.

Is it true that $[HK:H]$ will divide both $[G:H]$ and $|H|$? Why is this?

Comment: Your post should contain all the information; the subject is supposed to be informative, not the first line of the post. You don’t start a letter on the envelope, you don’t start a post on the subject line.

Comment: Sorry @ArturoMagidin, I was just following what I had seen on other questions that were similar

Comment: And fo course, too much of a bother to fix it...

Comment: Well I trying to determine if $[K:K \cap H]$ and $|K \cap H|$ are relatively prime. I was hoping to use the fact that $[HK:H] = [K:H \cap K]$ to show this, as I know that will divide both $[G:H]$ and $|K|$, but it seems from your answer below, this won't work. I will have to search for another way.

Comment: $[HK:H] = |HK|/|H| = |H||K|/|H||H\cap K| = |K|/|H\cap K] = [K:K\cap H]$. $K\cap H\leq H$. So $|K\cap H|$ divides $|H|$, and $[K:K\cap H]$ divides $[G:H]$. Hence, they are coprime.

Comment: Thank you @ArturoMagidin, I am sorry that I didn't edit the question imeediately.

Comment: @TopherNoms Regarding titles (for future reference), titles ideally should purely be a summary of the question below, and should not contain any information that isn't found in the body. The title is there for people who are browsing to get a good idea about whether they can help you, or whether the question can help them. The body is where the actual question should reside. Have a +1 for being responsive to constructive criticism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is true that $[HK:H]$ divides $[G:H]$: because $K$ is normal, $HK$ is certainly a subgroup that contains $H$, so $H\leq HK\leq G$, hence
$$[G:H]=[G:HK][HK:H],$$
proving that $[HK:H]$ divides $[G:H]$.

However, it need not be the case that $[HK:H]$ divides $|H|$. For a counterexample, take $C_6$, the cyclic group of order $6$, $K$ the subgroup of order $3$, and $H$ the subgroup of order $2$. We have $[G:H]=3$, and $|H|=2$, so $[G:H]$ and $|H|$ are coprime. But $HK=G$, so $[HK:H]=[G:H] = 3$, which certainly does not divide $|H|=2$.

---

In comments you state that what you actually want to do is prove that $[K:K\cap H]$ and $|K\cap H|$ are coprime.

Note that
$$[HK:H] = \frac{|HK|}{|H|} = \frac{|H||K|}{|H||H\cap K|}=\frac{|K|}{|H\cap K]} = [K:K\cap H].$$
So $[K:K\cap H]$ divides $[HK:H]$, which divides $[G:H]$.
On the other hand,
$K\cap H\leq H$. So $|K\cap H|$ divides $|H|$. Therefore, $[K:K\cap H]$ and $|K\cap H|$ are coprime.

Answer (score 1):

$HK\le G$, thus $|HK|\mid |G|$ by Lagrange.  Thus we have that $[HK:H]\mid[G:H]$ pretty easily by Lagrange.

But it is not true that  $[HK:H]\mid|H|$, in general.  For instance, in $A_4$, let $K=V_4$ and $H=\langle(123)\rangle$.  Then $HK=A_4$.  So $[HK:H]=4\not\mid3=|H|$.

---

(In fact, if $[G:H]$ and $|H|$ are coprime, then when $[HK:H]$ divides both,  $[HK:H]=1$, or $HK=H$.  This will probably help us find counterexamples.)